Where exactly are all the ‘millions’ of transistors present?
We often get to hear that there are millions of transistors in a computer.
Where exactly are these located?
The CPU involves clock, cache and registers.
The ALU / GPU would involve some transistors but I’m guessing they are not in the millions.
Is the above understanding correct?
Would it be the memory then?

Yes; The CPU has millions of transistors and an ALU and a often a GPU

A GPU would easily have multi millions of transistors - a typical gaming GPU will have 20-100 billion transistors.  (Per https://www.tomshardware.com/news/nvidia-reveals-secrets-of-ada-lovelace-gpus an RTX4090 contains 76.3 billion transistors)

According to Chat GPT which we all know is never ever wrong (but it does fit with my expectations) - the typical chip used in embedded IOT devices (eg the ESP8266) would include 1 and 3 million transistors.

In the old days (tens of thousands of transistors), you could see those in UV-erasable RAM with a microscope -- but new one as are too small., CPU's have caches with millions of transistors. Each cell has four or more transistors.

The days of millions of transistors on a CPU are over — you are typically talking in the 10's — low 100's of billions now.  (A first Gen i7 from 2010 had about 1 billion transistors, and "Moores Law" has more-or-less held steady with respect of transistor count)
Transistors are everywhere in the CPU — pretty much anything doing storage or calculation of any sort will be comprised of multiple transistors per bit — transistors are used as temporary storage and to build all the logic circuits - so every bit of on-chip memory or cache in the CPU would be made up of at least 1 transistor, and all the logic/functions would be multiple transistors.
Apparently a 1TB SSD has about 3 trillion transistors.

the number of transistors for a terabyte SSD never made sense to me, one TiB is 10 to the 12 bytes which would have 8 bits each, so that's 8 trillion bits, and assuming 2 or three transistors per bit, naiively it seems like it would have 16 to 24 trillion transistors. however, for anyone else wondering, i checked and it seems the latest NAND flash SSDs store three bits per transistor using a thing called triple level cell or TLC so that's about 3 trillion transistors, just as the answer says ... today i learned!
